# How to generate this structure of chapter /section /subsection tree like the example?

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I like to have a structure like this (From Introduction chapter/section) [ Ignore the red boxes]

[image: Desired output]

With the chapter looks like

[image: Actual chapter]

However, what I am getting is this

[image: My Output]

The MWE for main file is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,chapterprefix=TRUE]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum} % For generating dummy text
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[pass,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[a4,frame,center]{crop}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % for underline with normalem option
\usepackage{ragged2e} % For justified text
%\usepackage{titlesec} % Suppress leading zero in section
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
% Math packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage[center]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mdwmath}
\usepackage{mdwtab}
\usepackage{euler}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{makeidx}         % allows index generation
\usepackage{multicol}        % used for the two-column index
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}% places footnotes at page bottom
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
%Table packages
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 1fil}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\footnotesize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newenvironment{calligraphic}{\usefont{T1}{pzc}{m}{it}}{}
\newenvironment{conditions}
  {\par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\noindent\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} l}}
  {\end{tabular}\par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}
% Add your abbreviations here
% Example
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks   = true, %Colours links instead of ugly boxes
  urlcolor     = blue, %Colour for external hyperlinks
  linkcolor    = blue, %Colour of internal links
  citecolor   = red %Colour of citations
}
\geometry{
  top=5cm,
  bottom=5cm,
  left=2cm,
  right=2cm,
  paperwidth=\textwidth,
  paperheight=\textheight
}

\makeindex

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\KOMAoptions{open=left}
\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\KOMAoptions{open=right}
\restoregeometry
\mainmatter
\clearpage
\pagestyle{plain}
\include{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

And the code for Introduction.tex is

```
\chapter*{Chapter 1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{Motivation}
\lipsum[3-5]
Write Motivation of the research work
\subsection{Contribution}
\lipsum[5-6]
Write the thesis contribution
\subsection{Organization of thesis}
\lipsum[2-3]
Brief description of chapters in the thesis.
\subsubsection{Chapter 2: Literature Survey}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsubsection{Chapter 3:}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsubsection{Chapter 4:}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsubsection{Chapter 5:}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsubsection{Chapter 6:}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsubsection{Chapter 7:}
\lipsum[1-2]
```

It will be very nice if I can also have the footer with page number like
[image: Footer]

Comment: You are using the starred Version: `\chapter*{Chapter 1}`, thus its unnumbered. Why don't just try it with the regular command?

Comment: First of all, have a look into the `log` file. There are warning messages because of some packages. Remove at least them. Then use a simple `\chapter{Introduction}` without the `\chapter*{…}` and `\addcontentsline` before.

Comment: BTW: IMHO deducing the document preamble to make a real [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) would have lead you to the root of your problems and probably even to the solution. Overfraught document preambles are often a source of harm.

Comment: @cabohah My latex knowledge is very limited and I am trying to improve it with you guy's suggestions. I know there are some redundant packages (even conflicting packages) but do not have enough knowledge to identify them. That is why I have listed all the packages that I used in the OP.

Comment: Minimizing the document preamble is the method not only to identify such issues, but also to solve them. And reading the warning messages inside the `log` file also helps. BTW: IMHO it is seldom a good idea for novices to start with a so called *template* or example documents, e.g., from a classmate. These are not only often difficult to understand, but unfortunately also often poorly made. Because of this, it is mostly better, to start with a minimal document and to add only those packages and definitions, really needed.

Comment: Unfortunately,  this thesis template was taken from one of my seniors only 

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking to complicated. What you want is either standard class `book` with package `tocbibind` or KOMA-Script class `scrbook` (*without packages like `tocbibind`!*) with options `listof=totoc` (to add the list of … to the table of contents), option `chapterprefix` (to have chapters with “Chapter X” prefix line), and option `sfdefaults=false` (to not use sans serif fonts for the titles):

```latex
\documentclass[listof=totoc,chapterprefix,sfdefaults=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures

\addchap{Acknowledgment}
\addchap{Abstract}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-3]
\section{Motivation}
\lipsum[3-5]
Write Motivation of the research work
\section{Contribution}
\lipsum[5-6]
Write the thesis contribution
\section{Organization of thesis}
\lipsum[2-3]
Brief description of chapters in the thesis.
\subsection{Chapter 2: Literature Survey}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{Chapter 3:}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{Chapter 4:}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{Chapter 5:}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{Chapter 6:}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{Chapter 7:}
\lipsum[1-2] 
\end{document}
```

[image: Contents]

[image: Chapter]

The page footer would be another question. It could indeed be done using `scrlayer-scrpage`. If you have problems in doing it, please ask a new question with a proper minimal working example.

So remove at least the package(s) from the document preamble, that result in error messages, and all packages you are not using. And avoid dirty hacks like using `\chapter*{Chapter 1}`. KOMA-Script provides a lot of configuration options and commands. See the KOMA-Script manuals for more information.

Comment: The section and sub-section numbers in TOC are different from the actual section, subsection number format inside. The format in TOC is the desired format but inside the document it is different (eg. there is no 1.3.1 for Chapter 2 inside)

Comment: @Bukaida With my example, the number format in the document is the same as shown in the ToC. KOMA-Script allows to change this (e.g. redefining `\subsectionformat`). But I've not shown it, because the question wasn't about this. Please note: Always focus to one single problem. If you have additional questions, just ask additional questions. Avoid mixing several problems into one question.